# RSpec tests with Factory Girl creating image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, database-cleaner

In a rails 4.2.0 app I'm using RSpec and Factory Girl for tests. In the app I am using Paperclip for image uploads. When I run the tests with a blank image the image is being placed in the public folder.

Is there any way I can use the database_cleaner gem to fix this?

So far I have this:

spec\support\factory_girl.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
 config.before(:suite) do
  begin
    DatabaseCleaner.start
    FactoryGirl.lint
  ensure
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
 end
end
```

spec\support\database_cleaner.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

 config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
 end

 config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
 end

 config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
 end

 config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
 end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DatabaseCleaner` is for cleaning the database, not the file system. You can remove the file yourself instead, e.g. in an `after` block.

```
after(:each) { FileUtils.rm @file_path }
```

Comment: Oh right, I was under the impression from reading bits of documentation that it would. Cheers for the tip. Although how would define @file_path ?

Comment: @Koxi, You can pass the file path to the after block in various ways, e.g. define it in a `before` block. Or you can remove the file in the same example that you create it, and use the same path variable for both.